# Bubble sort dropped images based on their names

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, sorting, drag-and-drop

I have written a simple bubble sort function that sort an array of Image objects based on image names.
For some reason my function is not swapping the elements of array when needed ( basically new assignment is not working)

Here is my code :

```
        listOfFiles = event.dataTransfer.files;
        sortImages(listOfFiles);
        function sortImages(listOfFiles)
        {
            var re = /[0-9]/;
            var temp;
            for( var index=0; index < listOfFiles.length ; index++)
            {
                for ( var index2=0; index2 < listOfFiles.length-1 ; index2++)
                {
                    var one = parseFloat(re.exec(listOfFiles[index2].name ));
                    var two = parseFloat(re.exec(listOfFiles[index2+1].name));
                    console.log(one + " : " + two);
                    if (one > two) 
                    {
                        console.log(listOfFiles[index2+1]);
                        console.log(listOfFiles[index2]);
                        //following three lines don't work
                        temp = listOfFiles[index2+1];
                        listOfFiles[index2+1] = listOfFiles[index2];
                        listOfFiles[index2] = temp;


                        console.log(listOfFiles[index2+1]);
                        console.log(listOfFiles[index2]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: Hey sroves, No, I am not getting any error. Function runs fine, it just doesn't swap values. I added console.log() to print out the values and they remain same even after assigning any new value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be at `re.exec()` which returns an array.  You need to grab the first index which contains the matched characters.  See the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec.

The following should work:

```
listOfFiles = event.dataTransfer.files;
sortImages(listOfFiles);
console.log(listOfFiles);

function sortImages(listOfFiles) {
    var re = /[0-9]/;
    var temp;
    for (var index = 0; index < listOfFiles.length; index++) {
        for (var index2 = 0; index2 < listOfFiles.length - 1; index2++) {
            var one = parseFloat(re.exec(listOfFiles[index2].name)[0]); //here
            var two = parseFloat(re.exec(listOfFiles[index2 + 1].name)[0]); //here
            console.log(one + " : " + two);
            if (one > two) {
                console.log(listOfFiles[index2 + 1]);
                console.log(listOfFiles[index2]);
                //following three lines don't work
                temp = listOfFiles[index2 + 1];
                listOfFiles[index2 + 1] = listOfFiles[index2];
                listOfFiles[index2] = temp;

                console.log(listOfFiles[index2 + 1]);
                console.log(listOfFiles[index2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Vinod, Thanks for your reply. Image object looks like this : {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Mon Jun 03 2013 14:43:33 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), name: "1.png", type: "image/png", size: 161150…}

And because it does not have any element named "input" it gives me NaN.

Comment: Got it, I just had to update my answer after reading your question again.  Please give that a try.  And here is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/vinodadhikary/fuRJc/

Comment: I appreciate your help again. This code doesn't give me any error but the array is still unsorted. Here is the output when I traverse the array after sorting.

index : 0 : layer8.png 
index : 1 : layer1.png 
index : 2 : layer2.png 
index : 3 : layer3.png 
index : 4 : layer4.png 
index : 5 : layer5.png 
index : 6 : layer6.png 
index : 7 : layer7.png

Comment: Also, its happening only for image objects(dropped image array). When I pass simple array this function works fine.

Comment: Hey Vinod, got it working. There is something wrong the with array that is generated by dropping the files which doesn't get changed so I copied all the elements of an array to a new array and passed that new array to the function and it works fine.